# GUI menu in docker container freezes (ubuntu parent image)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, esp8266

I've been trying to run a docker container including the esp8266 toolchain and ESP8266_RTOS_SDK.
After the Dockerfile is done the 'Espressif IoT Menu' pops up but freezes instantly and I cant control anything. [Screenshot of the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6Vz4.png). I thought maybe I had to run the container endlessly, but it didn't help either. I tried this command: `RUN tail -f /dev/null`.
What else I thought is that the container might be missing some programs for a terminal?

**Here is my Dockerfile (first time working with docker):**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# -------------------------- TOOLCHAIN --------------------------------------
WORKDIR /
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN apt update && add-apt-repository universe
RUN apt-get -y install gcc wget git make libncurses-dev flex bison gperf python3 python3-serial python3-pip

RUN mkdir -p downloads esp8266
ADD https://dl.espressif.com/dl/xtensa-lx106-elf-linux64-1.22.0-100-ge567ec7-5.2.0.tar.gz downloads
RUN cd esp8266;tar -xzf /downloads/xtensa-lx106-elf-linux64-1.22.0-100-ge567ec7-5.2.0.tar.gz

ENV PATH=/esp8266/xtensa-lx106-elf/bin:$PATH

# -------------------------- ESP8266_RTOS_SDK ---------------------------------

RUN cd esp8266;git clone https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK.git
ENV IDF_PATH="/esp8266/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK"
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python #otherwise python wont be found
ENV TERM xterm #otherwise "terminal unknown"
RUN python3 -m pip install --user -r $IDF_PATH/requirements.txt
RUN cd esp8266;cp -r $IDF_PATH/examples/get-started/hello_world .
RUN cd /esp8266/hello_world;make menuconfig
```

**I run the container with:**

`sudo docker build -f $(pwd)/dEsp8266 -t espenv .`

**The guide's I used:**

For the toolchain: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp8266-rtos-sdk/en/latest/get-started/linux-setup.html

For the RTOS_SDK: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp8266-rtos-sdk/en/latest/get-started/index.html#get-started-get-esp-idf

Comment: That `docker build` command is how you build the image; what command are you using to launch the container?  What is the `CMD` the container should run?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It already helped me to fix my problem! I thought that with all the commands in the dockerfile, and then with `docker build`, I will be able to see the menu pop up perfectly. Now what I did is `sudo docker run -d --name containerName imageName tail -f /dev/null` to create a container with name`containerName`and then `sudo docker exec -it containerName bash`. After that I'm in a shell and can `make` the menu. (dont know exactly what was missing)